# speedup geolocation algorithm in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I have a set 100k of of geo locations (lat/lon) and a hexogonal grid (4k polygons). My goal is to calculate the total number of points which are located within each polygon.

My current algorithm uses 2 for loops to loop over all geo points and all polygons, which is really slow if I increase the number of polygons... How would you speedup the algorithm? I have uploaded a minimal example which creates 100k random geo points and uses 561 cells in the grid...

I also saw that reading the geo json file (with 4k polygons) takes some time, maybe i should export the polygons into a csv?

hexagon_grid.geojson file:
https://gist.github.com/Arnold1/9e41454e6eea910a4f6cd68ff1901db1

minimal python example:
https://gist.github.com/Arnold1/ee37a2e4b2dfbfdca9bfae7c7c3a3755

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to explicitly test each hexagon to see whether a given point is located inside it.

Let's assume, for the moment, that all of your points fall somewhere within the bounds of your hexagonal grid. Because your hexagons form a regular lattice, you only really need to know which of the hexagon centers is closest to each point.

This can be computed very efficiently using a [`scipy.spatial.cKDTree`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
import json

with open('/tmp/grid.geojson', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

verts = []
centroids = []

for hexagon in data['features']:

    # a (7, 2) array of xy coordinates specifying the vertices of the hexagon.
    # we ignore the last vertex since it's equal to the first
    xy = np.array(hexagon['geometry']['coordinates'][0][:6])
    verts.append(xy)

    # compute the centroid by taking the average of the vertex coordinates
    centroids.append(xy.mean(0))

verts = np.array(verts)
centroids = np.array(centroids)

# construct a k-D tree from the centroid coordinates of the hexagons
tree = cKDTree(centroids)

# generate 10000 normally distributed xy coordinates
sigma = 0.5 * centroids.std(0, keepdims=True)
mu = centroids.mean(0, keepdims=True)
gen = np.random.RandomState(0)
xy = (gen.randn(10000, 2) * sigma) + mu

# query the k-D tree to find which hexagon centroid is nearest to each point
distance, idx = tree.query(xy, 1)

# count the number of points that are closest to each hexagon centroid
counts = np.bincount(idx, minlength=centroids.shape[0])
```

Plotting the output:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, subplot_kw={'aspect': 'equal'})
ax.hold(True)
ax.scatter(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 10, c='b', alpha=0.25, edgecolors='none')
ax.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1], marker='h', s=(counts + 5),
           c=counts, cmap='Reds')
ax.margins(0.01)
```

[image]

I can think of several different ways you could handle points that fall outside your grid depending on how much accuracy you need:

- You could exclude points that fall outside the outer bounding rectangle of your hexagon vertices (i.e. `x < xmin`, `x > xmax` etc.). However, this will fail to exclude points that fall within the 'gaps' along the edges of your grid.
- Another straightforward option would be to set a cut-off on `distance` according to the spacing of your hexagon centers, which is equivalent to using a circular approximation for your outer hexagons.
- If accuracy is crucial then you could define a `matplotlib.path.Path` corresponding to the outer vertices of your hexagonal grid, then use its [`.contains_points()` method](http://matplotlib.org/api/path_api.html#matplotlib.path.Path.contains_points) to test whether your points are contained within it. Compared to the other two methods, this would probably be slower and more fiddly to code.

Comment: looks great. i currently have the grid structured big enough, so that there are no points outside... i also love the visualization. is it also easy to plot it on google maps running as a webserver?

Comment: Matplotlib itself has no provision for this. You might want to take a look at [gmplot](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmplot/1.0.5) instead.

Comment: ok will look into gmplot. is it possible to make the cells within your matplot example equal size and only use the color to indicate the frequency? e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/ts4oyyn0/10/

Comment: Yes, look at the docstring for `plt.scatter`. You should also be aware that matplotlib has a built in function for plotting hexagonally binned histograms (`plt.hexbin`), although I'm not sure about its relative performance.