# Iterating over rows of a pandas dataframe, finding point of minimum distance in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, latitude-longitude

I have two very large (+100000 rows) `pandas` data frames. Both frames have lists of points with geographical data, and what I am trying to do is find the data from the closest point in the second frame and place it with the corresponding entry in the first. I currently have the following code:

```
Data1['MatchInd'] = None
for i, row in Data1.iterrows():
    Dist = (Data2['x'] - row['x'])**2 + (Data2['y'] - row['y'])**2
    Data1['MatchInd'][i] = Dist.idxmin()
```

While there is nothing wrong with this, it is very slow, and involves a loop over rows. I was curious if anyone had a better idea?

Best,

Matt

Comment: look at `scipy.spatial` and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37169643/speedup-geolocation-algorithm-in-python) might be interesting for you as well...

Comment: @MaxU -- the `cKDTree` solved my problem wonderfully. All the best, Matt